# Pass container of raw pointers and smart pointers to template function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, unique-ptr

Is there a possibility to abstract the pointer type of objects from a container when the container (e.g.: `std::vector`) is passed to a function template?

I have the following two methods:

```
template <typename T, typename allocT, template <typename, typename> class containerT>
static void parse(containerT<T *, allocT> &entries, const rapidjson::Value &jsonDocument)
{
    for (rapidjson::SizeType entryIt = 0; entryIt < jsonDocument.Size(); ++entryIt)
    {
        entries.push_back(new T());
        entries[entryIt]->parse(jsonDocument[entryIt]);
    }
}
```

and

```
template <typename T, typename allocT, template <typename, typename> class containerT>
static void parse(containerT<std::unique_ptr<T>, allocT> &entries, const rapidjson::Value &jsonDocument)
{
    for (rapidjson::SizeType entryIt = 0; entryIt < jsonDocument.Size(); ++entryIt)
    {
        entries.push_back(std::move(std::unique_ptr<T>(new T())));            
        entries[entryIt]->parse(jsonDocument[entryIt]);
    }
}
```

Let's ignore the `std::move` call for now. As you can see, these two methods almost do the same thing, except when pushing back new objects. It would be better if I could have only one method.

How can this be achieved? Is `decltype` any useful? I couldn't find a way to do this.

The rationale behind needing this is that the old code calls the method with raw pointers and the new code with smart pointers, so a fast switch to the new mode is not possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`std::pointer_traits<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/pointer_traits):

```
template <typename P, typename allocT, template <typename, typename> class containerT>
static void parse(containerT<P, allocT> &entries, const rapidjson::Value &jsonDocument)
{
    for (rapidjson::SizeType entryIt = 0; entryIt < jsonDocument.Size(); ++entryIt)
    {
        entries.emplace_back(new typename std::pointer_traits<P>::element_type());
        //                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
        entries[entryIt]->parse(jsonDocument[entryIt]);
    }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0667a37200d40e44)